# LINQ To Entity - Unique Left Outer Join Scenerio

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, left-join

I am trying to write the following Left Outer Join scenerio in Linq to Entity syntax and I can't for the life of me figure out exactly how to pull it off...  **Here is the working SQL** that I am trying to ultimately achieve:

SELECT *
FROM Students s
LEFT JOIN ParentStudents ps ON ps.StudentId = s.StudentId **AND ps.ParentId = '6D279F72-2623-459F-B701-5C77C52BA52F'**

WHERE s.TenantId = 3 AND s.FamilyId = '28833312-46eb-4a54-9132-8a7c8037cec5'

The part highlighted in Bold is where I fall down ... I want Students to return regardless if there are any ParentStudent records in the database.

Here is my latest LINQ to Entity **code that does not work**:

```
    public ICollection<ParentStudentListing> GetParentStudents(Guid FamilyId, Guid ParentId)
    {
        var query = from s in DataContext.Students
                    from ps in s.ParentStudents.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    where s.TenantId == CurrentUser.TenantId && s.FamilyId == FamilyId && ps.ParentId == ParentId
                    select new ParentStudentListing { StudentId = s.StudentId, FirstName = s.FirstName, MiddleName = s.MiddleName, LastName = s.LastName, RelationshipId = ps.RelationshipId, ParentStudentId = ps.ParentStudentId, isAllowedToPickUp = ps.isAllowedToPickUp, isEmergency = ps.isEmergency, isLiveIn = ps.isLiveIn, ParentId = ps.ParentId };

        return query.ToList();
    }
```

This code does not bring back students unless there are ParentStudent records in the database which is not the intended result.   I want to bring back students regardless if there are ParentStudent records, but if there are ParentStudent records I want those joined up with the Student records...

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Joe for the added help .... That didn't quite get me there, but I did finally get it running.  Here is the working code:

```
    public ICollection<ParentStudentListing> GetParentStudents(Guid FamilyId, Guid ParentId)
    {
        var query = from s in DataContext.Students
                    join ps in DataContext.ParentStudents
                          on new { s.StudentId, ParentId = ParentId }
                      equals new { ps.StudentId, ps.ParentId } into ps_join
                    from ps in ps_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    where s.TenantId == CurrentUser.TenantId && s.FamilyId == FamilyId
                    select new ParentStudentListing { StudentId = s.StudentId, FirstName = s.FirstName, MiddleName = s.MiddleName, LastName = s.LastName, RelationshipId = ps.RelationshipId, ParentStudentId = ps.ParentStudentId, isAllowedToPickUp = ps.isAllowedToPickUp, isEmergency = ps.isEmergency, isLiveIn = ps.isLiveIn, ParentId = ps.ParentId };

        return query.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Joe you answer was just as helpful!  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my first attempt at a LINQ join:

```
var query = from s in DataContext.Students
            join ps in s.ParentStudents on ps.ParentId equals s.ParentId into ps
            from ps in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where s.TenantId == CurrentUser.TenantId && s.FamilyId == FamilyId                
            select new ParentStudentListing { StudentId = s.StudentId, FirstName = s.FirstName, MiddleName = s.MiddleName, LastName = s.LastName, RelationshipId = ps.RelationshipId, ParentStudentId = ps.ParentStudentId, isAllowedToPickUp = ps.isAllowedToPickUp, isEmergency = ps.isEmergency, isLiveIn = ps.isLiveIn, ParentId = ps.ParentId };
```

Referenced from [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Join-Operators-dabef4e9).